# C++ If Else Statements not functioning properly

Tags: c++

The code is compiling and all, but it doesn't function as it should. The first if statement is working properly, but it is when it attempt to test the other functions that it doesn't do what it should. It will just add on it on to the value it is displaying. Please, and thank you in advance for the help.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

        // b representing Balance, Fee is self-explanitory
        int b = 0;
        float fee = 0;
        std::cout << "Enter the beginning balance of your bank account:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> b;  

        if (b < 400) {  
                fee = 25;
        } 
        else {                          
                fee = 10;
        }       

        // if, else if statements for check fees
        int c = 0;      
        std::cout << "Enter the amount of checks written this month" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> c;                    
        if (c < 20) {   
                float cf = 0.10;
                cf *= c;
                fee += cf; 
                std::cout << "Your bank fees for this month will be: $"
                        << fee << std::endl;
                return 0;                 
        } else if (c = 20 && c <= 39) {
                float cf = 0.08; 
                cf *= c;
                fee += cf; 
                std::cout << "Your bank fees for this month will be: $"
                                        << fee << std::endl;
                return 0;
        } else if (c = 40 && c <= 59) {
                float cf = 0.06;
                cf *= c;
                fee += cf;
                std::cout << "Your bank fees for this month will be: $"
                        << fee << std::endl;
                return 0;
        } else (c >= 60) ;{
                float cf = 0.04;
                cf *= c;
                fee += cf;
                std::cout << "Your bank fees for this month will be: $"
                        << fee << std::endl;
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please indent consistently.

Comment: What is the test case you are trying to test for and what are your expected results and what are your results?

Comment: Test case would be the following inputs: B= 300  C = 25. The result should be 27, but it gives 25.08.

Comment: Your final `else` bit compiles, but doesn't do anything, and the final block is always executed. Finding out why is a good exercise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I fixed the indentation for you this time, but please make sure to format correctly when posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You should compare values using `==` not by using `=`. A single equals sign only does an assignment. EDIT: actually after looking closer at the code it would make more sense to replace the single `=` with `>=` to check for greater or equals. And if that is the case you can remove the first check overall as `else if` will already make sure it is true.
- The semi-colon here is erraenous: `}else (c >= 60) ;{` resulting in the code doing not what you expect.

Comment: he shouldn't test for equality either.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it is not at all apparent what OP should be doing but a single equals sign seems to be an error. Actually both single and double equals sign make the second check useless.

Comment: not quite, 20 passes the test ;) but it's clearly a bug.

Answer (score 5):

`=` is assignment. It should really be dropped from all your `else` branches:

```
if (c < 20)
{
  //...
}
else if (c < 40)
{
  //...
}
else if (c < 60)
{
  //...
}
else
{
  //...
}
```

Also note that you have a stray `;` after the `else (c >= 60)` - and a missing `if`, for that matter, but the whole `if`would be superfluous there.

Answer (score 0):

```
}else if (c = 20 && c <= 39) {
```

This statement will set c to 20 and then check if c is 39 or less. Probably you meant

```
}else if (c >= 20 && c <= 39) {
```

?

If you just want to check if c is 20, use `c == 20`.

Answer (score -1):

```
c = 20
```

and

```
c = 40
```

should be `c == 20` and `c == 40`.

Comment: Come on this answer is correct and definitely should not be downvoted.